# Oscillation operator of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Call a function from $[0, 1]$ to itself a box function.

Given any box function $f$, define its oscillation function $Of$ as $$Of(x) = \lim _{d \to 0} \sup _{y, z \in B_d (x)} |f(y) - f(z)| \, .$$ Then $Of(x)$ is itself a box function.

---

Is it true that for every box function $f$, $OOOf = OOf$?

Comment: Here B_d (x) is the ball of radius d around x.

Comment: This was essentially [proved by Sierpinski in 1910](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015039476695;view=1up;seq=681) (reprinted on pp. 42-43 of Volume 2 of his **Oeuvres Choisies**), then generalized by Henry Blumberg [1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2370331) [2](https://www.jstor.org/stable/83861) [3](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2007120) to cases in which the oscillation is computed by allowing for the neglect of countable, measure zero, and first category sets. Although the result appears in a few books (e.g. Hahn's 1921 treatise on real functions) and papers, **(continued)**

Comment: it was not sufficiently well known to avoid rediscovery, which Donald C. Benson [did in 1960](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2309449). In recent years there has been some research done on certain properties of the oscillation function --- see the references at the end of my answer to [Oscillation of a Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/933781/13130).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

For a function $h(x)$ we denote by $LS(h)$, $LI(h)$ the functions defined as $$LS(h)(x)=\max(h(x),\limsup_{y\to x} h(y)),\\ LI(h)(x)=\min(h(x),\liminf_{y\to x} h(y)).$$

Then $$Og=LS(g)-LI(g).$$

Denote $g(x)=Of(x)$. Note that $g=LS(g)$, i.e. $$g(x)\geqslant \limsup_{y\to x} g(y).$$ Indeed, for any $d>0$ and any $a$ such that $|a-x|<d$, we have $\sup_{y,z\in B_d(x)} |f(y)-f(z)|\geqslant g(a)$, taking limsup in $a\to x$ we get $\limsup_{a\to x} g(a)\leqslant \sup_{y,z\in B_d(x)} |f(y)-f(z)|$, now take limit in $d\to 0$.

So we have $OOf=Og=g-LI(g)$, $OOOf=O(Og)=Og-LI(Og)$. Thus your relation $OOf=OOOf$ rewrites as $LI(Og)=0$. In other words, we should prove that for any $\varepsilon>0$, any $x\in [0,1]$  and and $d>0$ there exists $y\in (x-d,x+d)$ such that $Og(y)<\varepsilon$.  Denote $s=\inf_{(x-d,x+d)} g$ and choose $y\in (x-d,x+d)$ such that $g(y)<s+\varepsilon$. But $LI(g)(y)\geqslant s$ and we conclude that $Og(y)=g(y)-LI(g)(y)<\varepsilon$ as desired.

Comment: I think you meant $g:=Of$ (and then everything seems to work), rather than $g:=f$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis of course, thank you. Fixed.